# Creating WIndows 10 Tablet app that connects directly to SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Is there such a thing as developing a Windows 10 tablet app that can connect directly to a SQL Server database via ado.net, for example?

Or the only way to develop a Windows 10 app is by using a Windows Universal template and connecting to SQL Server through another app (ie. Web service / WCF)?

Thanks.

Comment: Please undelete the last questions...

Answer (score 0):

This response is for Android apps, but it should apply to Windows apps. The database doesn't physically live in your app, so you're going to need to communicate with a server somehow to retrieve data. This is usually done via Web API or some RESTful service. Your server code will communicate with the database. I'm not sure if apps can utilize a small resident database like SQLite or not - I've personally never tried it. Apps should be treated like they have limited storage space. All the apps I've worked on have used Web API, hit a service endpoint, and then talked to a SQL Server database. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a WCF Restful service returning Json between the WCF Restful service and the client application. The WCF Resful service is using a DAL. Or you use ASP.NET Web API accessing a DAL, ASP.NET WEB API is restful and Json based.

You should be concerned with SoC and using a DAL.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

You should be using DTO(s) in sending a single DTO between the client and service or a List of DTO(s) and not datasets or datatables in any SOA type solution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

The DAL can use the Repository or DAO pattern. And the DAL can use straight up ADO.NET with SQL command objects and T-SQL or use the ADO.NET Entity Framework.